# Sorting Vectors based on their correlation

Tags: sorting, correlation

This problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338646/sort-vectors-according-to-their-distance-between-them is about sorting vectors based on the distance between them. What about sorting vectors based on the correlation coefficient between them. What I want to do is to sort vectors based on their "importance" in the dataset. If we have N vectors then the sorting will be V1,V2,...,Vn where V1 and Vn are less correlated then the others. V1 and V2 are most correlated whith each other...and so on. I was thinking to use Pearsons Coefficient as a correlation coefficient. Is this possible or do you have any idea about this issue? And is there a good algorithm to do this or we should find the correlating coefficient between each pair of vectors and then find two less correlated ones and then sort all the vectors in between the two less correlated.

Thnx for reading and answering :)

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pearsons will work.  So will the usual dot product, Manhattan, etc.

You realize, of course, that this needs a *matrix*.

Vector 1 is perfectly correlated with itself, so its value is 1.0.  (Imagine that on the diagonal of the matrix.)  Then the next value (1, 2) shows how vector 1 is correlated with vector 2, and so on through (1, n).

The matrix is symmetric, because (i, j) = (j, i).

For `n` vectors there are `nxn` correlations to calculate.

Comment: thnx a lot. yes that`s right but it will take too much time. As you said the complexity is O(n^2). i wondered if there is any other algorithm for this purpose.

Comment: Nope, that's how long it takes.  How many vectors do you have?  No other algorithm.  If you're worried about time, parallelize it.  Have multiple threads do the calculations for you.  I'd guess N threads could do it in O(N).

Comment: yes you are right. actually i dont know the number of vectors. i was thinking to use this approach in Som algorithm to initialize it with "most important" vectors in the dataset. actually i am not sure what`s the difference between sorting based on distance and based on correlation coefficient. i dont know which is better in the case of SOM. if i want to osrt based on distance i found out that coVenx hull has o(n* log n) complexity...do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Distance is just one measure among many for correlation.  "Better" is not a black and white consideration.  You should write your code so you can plug in different measures and evaluate the results they give you.  "Better" depends on you and your problem.  One size does not fit all.

Comment: Well I want to use pearson coefficient instead because i have a feeling that it is better in the SOM case but it will take more time. Anyway i will try both of them. Thnx a lot :)

Comment: You have a "feeling".  You keep insisting it will "take more time" without any data either way.  My suggestion is to get some and stop relying on your feelings.  This is not faith based computing - it's called computer science.